# Dotnet WebApi - Upload error (largefile) in hosted Azure App Service

Tags: c#, azure, file-upload, azure-web-app-service

First - locally all is working like expected with files of every kind of size. I use a large file upload service which is working with chunks. In the controller I use the following attributes to make a large file upload happen:

```
[DisableFormValueModelBinding]
[DisableRequestSizeLimit]
```

The api is hosted in azure app service with following service plan (P3V2
840 total ACU
14 GB memory
Dv2-Series compute equivalent
284.41 EUR/Month (Estimated)) - I think this should be sufficient. However in this location I always get an "(failed)net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR" when uploading files bigger than 2 GB. In application insights no exception is listed. A controller log in the first line will not be logged, so my assumption is that the app service cut the request before - but why? I can not find any infos to set up   a max allowed body size or something. So it must be possible to upload larger files than 2 GB on azure service app. How can I set up the app service to provide a larger file upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had a meeting with guys from Azure and they said that there is a limitation on linux machines. When the request is higher than 2GB, the request will be blocked before it came to the application itself. And there is one other limitation here - if the request takes more than 230sec than the request will be  run into a timeout... So if you plan to upload files then the recommendation is to use the javascript client lib to upload the file directly to the azure blob storage and go from there.

This is really annoying, but you can not configure or change these kind of limitations like in k8s or iis, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Validate the length of the file ( maxRequestLength) in web.config in your Application.

In web.config --> <system.web> tag
Add the below code,

```
 <httpRuntime targetFramework="*.*.*" maxRequestLength="1073741824" >
```

In <system.webServer> tag -->  Add Security tag ,

```
<security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
            </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Configure the handler in web.config (handlers tag)

```
 <handlers>
        <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <httpPlatform processPath="%DNX_PATH%" arguments="%DNX_ARGS%" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" startupTimeLimit="3600"  />
```

You can upload Large files by sending the blob with smaller blocks.
Please follow the [link](https://www.andrewhoefling.com/Blog/Post/uploading-large-files-to-azure-blob-storage-in-c-sharp) for reference .

Comment: No this is not the problem... I do not publish on IIS... I do not have/need a web.config! -> "The web.config is a file that is read by IIS and the ASP.NET Core Module to configure an app hosted with IIS."